# how to refresh a jsf page from a JavaBean

Tags: java, jsf, refresh

I want to refresh an XHTML page (jsf) or part of this page, when a variable in a manageBean changes the value.

**The problem is:**

I have a JavaBean, which receives data from a webService. This data changes regularly. when a variable changes value, I want to display it in the IHM page.

I want that my application detects these changes and refresh the page automatically.

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO it's not the best way to refresh a view out of the backend. Most of those cases can be avoided by doing a partial request triggered from the view. I would like to give you a hand but for doing so I'll need to see some of your code and maybe a detailed explanation of what you want to do. Cheers!

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, depending on the concrete functional requirement and the available/used libraries. This information is however completely missing in your question. Please edit and improve your question to elaborate more about them.

Comment: the problem is :

  I have a JavaBean, which receives data from a webService. this data changes regularly. when a variable changes value, I want to display it in the IHM page.

I want that my application detects these changes and refresh the page automatiquely

Comment: There is no push in html, so you need to let the page check every x time. Call the bean and let the bean call the webservice to see if teh value has changed.

Comment: @roel That's not quite true, look at [Comet](http://cometd.org/) (and probably a bunch of other tools) for instance. Server-to-client communication is a very important problem for Web 2.0 apps and it's not exactly being ignored. (That said, Comet isn't a JSF technology and it might not be particularly convenient to integrate it. It depends on the OP's requirements if it's the right solution compared to long polling.)

Comment: @roel: there's also web sockets (which PrimeFaces Push is using).

Comment: thx for your responses !

to summarize. I understand that the communication `server> IHM` is impossible. or IHM   must ask the changes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax polling. Demos:

- [RichFaces 3.3 Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf)
- [RichFaces 4.x Demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=poll)
- [PrimeFaces 3.4 Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf)

Note that RichFaces 3.3 works with JSF 1.2 and JSF 2, RichFaces 4.x and PrimeFaces 3.x works with JSF 2.x

Comment: I think that I have a half of  I'm looking for. thank you friend

Answer (score 1):

One quick way would be to use a third-party library like [PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org)

This library includes a component called **[poll](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml)** with wich you can check your backend in a preset interval and update your view component(s) on changes.
Check out the link to see an easy example.

Hope this helpes. Have Fun!

Comment: thx for your responses !

to summarize. I understand that the communication `server> IHM` is impossible. or IHM   must ask the changes !

Comment: It is hardly possible/bad practice. The request to show/update the view has already been sent, therefore there is no communication between view and backend unless you trigger it by an action component like *button* or *poll*. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use poll option of ajax in jsf like

```
<a4j:poll interval="timeinms" reRender="jsfcomponent"> </a4j:poll>
```

Comment: can me specify a dynamical timeinms ?